# Google Chrome extension and SWF flash file

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, flash, manifest

I am trying to create a google chrome extension which requires copy to clipboard functionality. I have researched and found that the only cross browser solution is the zero clipboard library but I cant seem to figure out how I would add the swf file of the zero clipboard to my extension package. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

1) if you are writting a chrome extension why are you looking for cross-browser functionality?
2) use the native chrome clipboard permission. From your background page you can copy and paste (google it, its done by setting the html selection and issuing a copy command). If you want to copy from content, send the html to the background and from there set it to a div on background.html. ive done this on an extension i have published (plus for trello) so look at its source if not clear.

Comment: Thank you,
Could you also help me with another issue I am having.
Basically I need to copy all the text from the open tab that has the same font-size as the text that is selected. Hence I need some way to get the content of the whole page into a string variable so that I can perform operations on it and extract only the required data. Is there any way I can get the source of a highlighted tab in javascript for my extension

Comment: Inject a content script on all pages. Not sure where you will place the command to the user. If its in the page its easy but outside you would need to communicate with the currently active tab's content page. Im sure theres some native way to do it in chrome. If not you can send a message to background which csn broadcast to registered content scripts and only the active one responds.

Comment: Thank you again,
Although i am wondering if there is a way to interact with an activeTab like it is linked to my js file. Like if the web page open in my current tab had the <script src="script.js"> tag. Is there a way to gimmick this as I need to use document.getelementbyID(id), just that it needs to be for the currently open tab.

Comment: You can from a content script